# How do I proceed when I want to show another language when the actual language is deactivated?

Tags: language

I have two languages (German and French).
In my sections I have German enabled as default language. French is off by default.

My Problem is: 
I always want to show content, even if the other language is disabled and, when an entry is not translated yet, show a note like "Entry not translated yet."

I know about localeEnabled and status and I can query the following way:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('referenzen').localeEnabled(false).status(null).find() %}
```

That outputs all of the entries.
But I am running into problems with the "_entry" template.

And I don't really know how to differentiate between entries that have their status turned off vs. entries that only have a language turned off.

Does anybody have a solution to this problem?

Cheers
Stefan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So thanks to Brad I found this solution:

```
{# Get all entries regardless if the locale is enabled or not #}
{% set allEntries = craft.entries.section('yourSection').status(null).localeEnabled(false).find() %}

{# Set the other locale (could be done differently, but since I have only two, I chose the easy way) #}
{% if craft.locale == 'de' %}{% set otherLocale = 'fr' %}{% else %}{% set otherLocale = 'de' %}{% endif %}

{# Get all entries that are not disabled regardless if the locale is enabled or not #}
{% for entry in allEntries if entry.enabled == 1 %}

    {# if the locale is turned off, search for the entry in the other language #}
    {% if entry.status == 'disabled' and entry.localeEnabled == 0 %}

        {# Get the same entry in the other locale #}
        {% set otherEntry = craft.entries.id(entry.id).locale(otherLocale).first() %}

        <h2><a href="{{ otherEntry.url }}">{{ otherEntry.title }} ({{ otherLocale|upper }})</a></h2>

    {% else %}
        <h2><a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a></h2>
    {% endif %}

{# else (for the loop) all the entries are disabled #}
{% else %}
    <p>No results</p>
{% endfor %}
```

It works great for my case.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted!

Answer (score 0):

From your template you can check if the entry is enabled via [entry.enabled](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/entrymodel#enabled).

If an entry's locale is set to disabled (either via being disabled by default in the section's settings or manually on an entry), then the overall entry's [status](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/entrymodel#status) will be `disabled` as well.

If, for whatever reason, you need to see all of the locales for an entry and their `enabledByDefault` status, you can do something like:

```
<ul>
    {% for key, value in entry.getLocales() %}
        <li>locale = {{ key }}, enabledByDefault = {{ value['enabledByDefault'] }}
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot brad, my brain mixed up {{ entry.enabled }} and {{ entry.status }}. So {{ entry.status }} is 0 if {{ entry.localeEnabled }} is 0 OR {{ entry.enabled }} is 0. This is perfect! Thanks!

Comment: I am trying to do the following: {% set entries = craft.entries.section('referenzen').status(null).localeEnabled(false).enabled('1‌​').find() %} but the enabled('1') part doesn't work. Do I have to do it differently?